# How to send ping notification through Coinbase Api v2?

Tags: api, notifications, ping, coinbase-api

I'm trying to  receive "wallet:addresses:new-payment" notification using Coinbase Api. But automatic sending to my server is not working.

So I want to send "ping" notification to my server to check is everything is ok.
Description of their API is saying that "Ping notification can be send at any time to verify that the notification URL is functioning"
https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?shell#notification-resource 
But can't find how to send ping.

P.S. I set notification url in Api setting in my profile. And i can get the list of notifcations of my address. All notifications are there.
https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?shell#list-address39s-transactions

Hope you can help me to find the way to send a ping.
Thanks.

Comment: Have You found out the solution? I'm having the same problem

Comment: same issue here

Comment: Does this issue solve now?

Answer (score -2):

You send ping a similar way you would send any notification type like: `wallet:addresses:new-payment` or `wallet:buys:completed`.

This is how you would send a ping:

```
{
  "id": "6bf0ca21-0b2f-5e8a-b95e-7bd7eaccc338",
  "type": "ping",
  "data": {},
  "additional_data": {},
  "user": {
    "id": "f01c821e-bb35-555f-a4da-548672963119",
    "resource": "user",
    "resource_path": "/v2/users/f01c821e-bb35-555f-a4da-548672963119"
  },
  "account": {
    "id": "8d5f086c-d7d5-58ee-890e-c09b3d8d4434",
    "resource": "account",
    "resource_path": "/v2/accounts/8d5f086c-d7d5-58ee-890e-c09b3d8d4434"
  },
  "delivery_attempts": 0,
  "created_at": "2019-07-23T19:15:06Z",
  "resource": "notification",
  "resource_path": "/v2/notifications/6bf0ca21-0b2f-5e8a-b95e-7bd7eaccc338"
}
```

Comment: @repepeatercreeper so does it answer your question?

Comment: It would be nice if the one downvoting the answer would what issue did he face so I could improve the answer.  This way I don't know the reason and can hardly improve it.